# How to secure docker? Trade-offs between docker security decisions

Tags: linux, docker, security, root, sudo

Background, I want to give people on my team the ability to create and run docker images for developing portable in-house analysis pipelines.

As a total noob who doesn't want to create security problems on this server, should I:

1. Add users to the docker group (and don't worry),
2. give users permission to 'sudo docker',
3. go for rootless mode,
4. go for userns-remap mode,
5. configure docker to listen on a (local) TCP port or
6. put docker on a VM and open the TCP port?

I'm not /super/ concerned about security, e.g. I don't want to open the TCP port to the WAN and I don't want to give my users 'full' sudo on this server, but I'm not that concerned about them pulling off a CVE to get root...

Any insight into the trade-offs of the various choices listed above would be welcome. e.g. I have the feeling that the docker group and sudo docker options are equivalent in terms of side effects... not sure though!

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: depends on the user (public user or a colleague) and the reason for giving a user a container (public sandbox or in-house), all considerations of how tight you should make it , both situations dont need access to the host.. whats opening a port got to do with your question how would users connect?

Comment: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-73-connecting-to-a-remote-docker-daemon